# How to use mongoose data in express render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm using [Hackathon-starter](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter) and i want to use the name of the user from the database in the render title property in express.js

the file that i want to modify is [here](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/blob/master/controllers/user.js#L122)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: `req.user.name`

```js
exports.getAccount = function(req, res) {
  res.render('account/profile', {
    title: req.user.name
  });
};
```